# Setting Powershell output to a variable

Tags: powershell

So I'm working on a script that will have a variable set to a file path, then it will Get-ChildItem of that path and if these items are over a certain size then it will print the output of that with the name of the file and the file size.

```
Get-ChildItem $file | ? {$_.Length -gt 1mb} | ForEach-Object {Write-Host "Users:" $_.name "have Outlook Data Files larger than 8gb, with a total of" ("{0:N2}" -f($_.length/1mb)) "mb"}
```

I am trying to assign this output, to a variable so I can utilize the second command and send this output in an email to myself. Unless there is a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: We need to know what's not working... Where's the rest of your code? Help us help you.

Comment: `Write-Host` results go directly to a display. The correct cmdlet to use is `Write-Output`.

Comment: @rpm192 It's not that it's not working, I just am unsure how how to set the output of the above line of code to a variable so I can call it in a Send-MailMessage on the next line.

Comment: @LoganGregory - as JosefZ pointed out ... you are sending things to the _screen_. if you want to capture the _current_ screen output, remove the `Write-Host` stuff and let things go to the output stream. THEN add a `$VarName = ` in front of your line of code.

Comment: I guess I'm not quite understanding because when I use ? {Write-Output $final = "Users:" ... it seems to work but when I try and call that variable it just outputs a return. Sorry guys, it's my second week with powershell. And I appreciate the replies.

Answer (score 1):

```
$content = gci -Recurse -File | ? { $_.Length -gt 40000 }
```

Include $content as the body of your email.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous comments have pointed out, it seems like your primary problem might be a misunderstanding about how the Write-* cmdlets work in PowerShell.  Write-Host outputs directly to the host/console, bypassing the [normal PowerShell output streams](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/). This can be illustrated quickly by running the following commands in a PowerShell session:

```
$MyVariable1 = Write-Host "Hello, World!"
$MyVariable2 = Write-Output "Hello, World!"
$MyVariable1
$MyVariable2
```

If you run the above, you'll find that $MyVariable1 has no value assigned (and you could actually test it for that with something like `$null -eq $MyVariable1`) but $MyVariable2 will have the value 'Hello, World!'.

For your example to work to get your output into a variable you would need to run something like the following:

```
$LargeFiles = Get-ChildItem $file | ? {$_.Length -gt 1mb} | ForEach-Object {Write-Output "Users:" $_.name "have Outlook Data Files larger than 8gb, with a total of" ("{0:N2}" -f($_.length/1mb)) "mb"}
```

To learn more about PowerShell output streams you might also want to read the [about_redirection article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-5.1).